# Fzaninotto Faker PHP Fatal Error

Tags: php, class, github, fatal-error, faker

I keep getting this error when I am trying to test Faker PHP from github on my server:

> Fatal error: Class 'Faker\Provider\en_US\Address' not found in /home/andrew/public_html/JeffWork/src/Faker/Provider/en_US/Address.php on line 6

Link: http://aswanson.net/JeffWork/test/test.php

All of the package files have been installed and uploaded properly, and the code on line 5 & 6 looks like:

```
class Address extends \Faker\Provider\en_US\Address
{
```

Comment: Does `vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Provider/en_US/Address.php` exist?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure whether the file exists in the folder where your referring for "/home/andrew/public_html/JeffWork/src/Faker/Provider/en_US/Address.php".

Please take a new update with composer with the following

```
composer require fzaninotto/faker
```

Now with the updated version 1.6, you will be able to solve this kind of issue make sure to use **autoload.php** in file where your using.

The following shows the snippet of usage

```
    <?php

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $person = new Faker\Provider\en_US\Person($faker);
    $address = new Faker\Provider\en_US\Address($faker);

    foreach(range(1,10) as $i){
        echo $address->address(),'<br/>';
    }
```

Cheers!